# Beautiful Soup - Unexpected output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, output

I am learning Beautiful Soup and I am following a short tutorial by Analytics Vidhya which can be found here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/10/beginner-guide-web-scraping-beautiful-soup-python/

The tutorial uses Beautiful Soup to scrap a webpage in Wikipedia: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India

I am running the commands in my Jupyter notebook and I get identical outputs except when I try to extract information from Table Tags.

The tutorial extracts content of specific table with the command:

```
  soup.find_all("table" , class_ = 'wikitable sortable plainrowheaders' )
```

Which results to the following output according to the tutorial:

[image]

However, when I run the same command I get a messy output that not very readable and looks like this:

```
   [<table class="wikitable sortable plainrowheaders">\n<tr>\n<th 
   scope="col">No.</th>\n<th scope="col">State or<br/>\nunion  
    territory</th>\n<th scope="col">Administrative capitals</th>\n<th   
    scope="col">Legislative capitals</th>\n<th scope="col">Judiciary
```

Can you explain the difference in the output?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: The tutorial output may be custom to ipython or may have been altered, or the output has changed with BeautifulSoup versions. The output is otherwise perfectly fine; note the `\n` newline *text* sections between the HTML elements, that line up with the line breaks in the tutorial.

Comment: I note that the tutorial uses `soup = BeautifulSoup(page)` and doesn't show that with the *current* version of BeautifulSoup you'd get a warning about s picking a parser. I also tested the output with iPython, and I don't get the newlines expanded from `\n` either.

Comment: I notice that the current wikipedia page table includes the header 'State or union territory', which is what I see in your scraping. That's not the same as what's in the tutorial. Clearly the wikipedia page has changed.

Comment: Yes I got a warning and I altered the command to include lxml as was suggested.  My question is more generally: How do I create a readable output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be the same output and it is just handled differently by your particular development environment. You can always import "pretty print" and see if that straightens things up:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(my_output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it out.  pprint(soup.find_all("table" , class_ = 'wikitable sortable plainrowheaders' ))  Unfortunately, I got the same mess.  How one deals with this problem in general?

Comment: This doesn't actually print out the same thing. @im7: the output of beautifulsoup just changed between versions.

Comment: @im7: you should only mark something as accepted unless it actually solved your problem. `pprint()` makes no difference here.

Comment: I appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer.

The printout can be rendered more readable using the prettify() method.  However, the find_all() method returns a ResultSet --which contains all the objects of the 
type 'Table' and the given attributes.  The prettify() method can not be applied to the ResultSet.  However, prettify() can be applied to the elements of the ResultSet returned by slicing.  Thus, to get a printable output of the Table we do the following:

```
  right_tables = soup.find_all("table" , class_ = 'wikitable sortable plainrowheaders' ) 
  print(right_tables[0].prettify())
```

This renders the following output, which is what I was looking for:

```
  <table class="wikitable sortable plainrowheaders">
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">
      No.
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      State or
      <br/>
         union territory
    </th>
```

etc